# Is it possible to prevent child components from being created if ng-content is not present in template?

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a tab component with a structure similar to this:

```
<tabs>
    <tab-item [title]="'Tab 1'">
        **child component that makes database calls in NgOnInit or NgAfterViewInit**
    </tab-item>
    <tab-item [title]="'Tab 2'">
        **child component that makes database calls in NgOnInit or NgAfterViewInit**
    </tab-item>
    <tab-item [title]="'Tab 3'">
        **child component that makes database calls in NgOnInit or NgAfterViewInit**
    </tab-item>
</tabs>
```

I have conditional logic to ensure that the child components are only rendered via ng-content if they are on the selected tab with the following snippet:

```
<ng-content *ngIf="selected"></ng-content>
```

While this works as anticipated from a UI perspective, it appears the child elements are still being created internally even though they are never rendered. This is something I would like to avoid since it is causing database calls that won't be needed until the user selects the appropriate tab.

I have created a greatly [simplified example](http://plnkr.co/PgxHQj5Ui092rNRkOmXW) to illustrate this. As you can see I have commented out the ng-content from the template of ChildComponent, but the call to console.log from the ThirdComponent is still firing.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I could probably create an interface on components that will be displayed in tabs and then call a custom method to trigger database calls rather than using the built-in Angular lifecycle methods, but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@MichalCafe/angulars-content-projection-trap-and-why-you-should-consider-using-template-outlet-instead-cc3c4cad87c9#.iltf043bp) to be extremely helpful in solving my problem.

I changed the template of my tab-item component to look like this:

```
<ng-content *ngIf="selected"></ng-content>
<template *ngIf="selected && templateRef" [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef"></template>
```

With templateRef being an input property:

```
@Input() templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

To use this component, I can now do the following:

```
<tabs>
    <tab-item [title]="'Tab 1'">
        **static content**
    </tab-item>
    <tab-item [title]="'Tab 2'" [templateRef]="tab2"></tab-item>
    <tab-item [title]="'Tab 3'" [templateRef]="tab3"></tab-item>
    <template #tab2>
        **child component that makes database calls in NgOnInit or NgAfterViewInit**
    </template>
    <template #tab3>
        **child component that makes database calls in NgOnInit or NgAfterViewInit**
    </template>
</tabs>
```

Anything that's inside of a template will only be loaded when the tab is selected, preventing an extremely heavy initial page load.

Comment: Thank you so much for documenting this. I'm having the exact same issue and I'm very surprised that this hasn't been tackled by angular's team (unless expected behaviour?). Definitively a no-no if you have many tabs and each tab makes heavy/db calls/etc... Though I'm curious if there isn't a simpler approach other than using template...